# Julia physics informed neural network

Tags: julia, ode, pde, flux.jl

Let's consider this equation:

[image]

with :  `0 < b < 1.`

I am new to julia programming, I am considering to solve this ODE equation using  NeuralPDE.jl.
Any idea how to write that physics informed neural network ode in julia framework ?

Comment: did you try coding up the model and see if it just works? I would think this example just works without doing anything fancy?

Comment: Thank you Chris for your reply. In fact, I have been trying to implement Maziar Raissi code at first, then I came across NeuralPDE.jl and DiffEqFlux.jl which I found  very interesting. The problem is that we have a time series data (non-stationary), then we use analytical solution to fit the curve for foracasting,. The idea is to use the ODE equation to regularize the fitting. The parameter K and b are equation parameters and evaluated at the same time as the neural network’s weights. I have just started learning Julia, and I will try to build the model.